# How to use mysqli on flight php framework

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, flightphp

Flight php documentation says how can we use PDO connection to database. For instance

```
Flight::register('db', 'PDO', array('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test','user','pass'));

$db = Flight::db();

$x=$db->query("SELECT * FROM `test_table` LIMIT 0, 30")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

But, how can we use MySQLi in FlightPHP?

---

If I replace PDO with mysqli I get this error

```
mysqli::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (2)
```

---

```
Flight::register('db', 'mysqli', array('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test','user','pass'));

$db = Flight::db();

$x=$db->query("SELECT * FROM `test_table` LIMIT 0, 30")->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: This would be better asked in the FlightPHP github repo. But you should be able to use the PDO example and change it to work with mysqli. The first argument ('db') is just the static function you're registering with flight, the second is the PHP class name (mysqli) and the third is an array of the values as you would normally send into the mysqli constructor ('db host', 'user', 'pass', 'db name')

Comment: I tried to replace PDO with mysqli, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and what didn't work as expected. Did you get any errors?

Comment: I tried with Flight::register('db', 'mysqli', array('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbn','user','pass'));

Comment: And I get this error mysqli::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (2)

Comment: Please try what I suggested in the first comment. And please add additional info to the question and not in comments

Comment: @Pajsije in the first comment you were advised to change 3rd argument to `register()` call, it must be an array of 4 elements: server address, login, password, database name. Your code is still using PDO arguments

Comment: Andriy, Thanks a lot. That was right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Andriy Maletsky I found where the mistake was.

```
Flight::register('db', 'mysqli', array('localhost','my_user','my_pass','my_dbname'));

$db = Flight::db();

$x = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `test_table` LIMIT 1")->fetch_assoc();

print_r($x);
```

Comment: For code formatting indent with four spaces or select it and use the `{}` button to do that automatically. `>` is for quoted text and doesn't style it correctly.

Comment: Nice. Actually, you don't need reference to. That's possible `Flight::db()->query("SELECT * FROM test_table LIMIT 1")->fetch_assoc();`